# Java - Read out system environment during startup

Tags: java, environment-variables, system

What is the best way to read out system environment in an Java application and class visibility function?

I need to e.g. os.name and have designed a class like

```
private String osName; 

private void readSystemSettings() {
    osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
}

public void printSystemSettings() {
    System.out.println(this.osName);
    ...
}

public SystemEnvironment() {
    readSystemSettings();       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

1. What are the best practice for getting those information? 
   Call this function always on start-up or only from time to time?
2. I want to read out those information as soon as the class get instantiated. Therefor the constructor is calling the `readSystemSettings()` function.

As this is information will always be the same during runtime, I actually need only no stance. Means all variables + functions shall be final. Or am I wrong?

3. If 2) is correct understanding, how to do?

Comment: This belongs to code review...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a class with all the variables marked as final and then initialize in a static block.

```
public class SystemProperties{

  public static final String OS_NAME;
  // other properties

  static{
    OS_NAME = System.getProperty("os.name");
    // initialize other properties

  }

}
```

Else, if you're in a managed environment like Spring or EJB, you can mark `SystemProperties` as `singleton` and initialize the variable in a method annotated with `@PostContruct`.

```
public class SystemProperties{

  public static String OS_NAME;
  // other properties

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
    OS_NAME = System.getProperty("os.name");
    // initialize other properties

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility class:

```
public final class Utilities {

    public static final String OS_NAME = System.getProperty("os.name");

    private Utilities() { } // utility classes can't be instantiated

}
```

This way, this property will only be initialized once, during your application startup. You can then access this property from everywhere in your code with `Utilities.OS_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is set globally you could do

```
enum SystemEnvironment {
    ;
    public static final String OS_NAME = System.getProperty("os.name");
```

or you could look ti up each time as you shouldn't be call it that often.

```
enum SystemEnvironment {
    ;
    public static getOsName() {
         return System.getProperty("os.name");
    }
```

if you are using it often I suggest creating some tests for it.

```
enum SystemEnvironment {
    ;
    public static final boolean IS_WINDOWS = getOsName().startsWith("Window");
    public static getOsName() {
         return System.getProperty("os.name");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OWNER library.

The OWNER API is a Java library with the goal of minimizing the code required to handle application configuration via Java properties files.

So to load properties you should create class like this

```
public interface MyConfig extends Config {
    @Key("os.name")
    String osName();
}
```

Then you can load config whenever you need:

```
ServerConfig cfg = ConfigFactory.create(MyConfig.class,
        System.getProperties(), 
        System.getenv()
);
System.out.println("Os name:" + cfg.osName());
```

For more information you can see the documentation http://owner.aeonbits.org/docs/usage/